# using only certain functions from a library?

Tags: c++, libraries, sqrt, cmath

i would like to use only certain functions from math.h (WITHOUT including the entire library)

for example, i need to use "sqrt" and "exp", but i have variables named "y1" (and possibly others) which conflict with definitions in math.h

how can i use only certain functions from a library like that?

i tried

```
#define sqrt cmath::sqrt
```

but that did not work, i have seen something like that before with

```
#define cout std::cout
```

i think, so i thought it might work.

any ideas?

Comment: yes, they are. i am multithreading.

Comment: What math.h are you referring to?  
The C-Runtime math.h?  Or the C++ standard library <math> (which doesn't have a .h)?  
Or something else entirely?

Comment: <cmath> which i believe uses math.h

Comment: A variable like `y1` should not conflict with anything declared in any standard header. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: driver.cpp:18: error: ‘float y1’ redeclared as different kind of symbol 

/usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:524: error: previous declaration of ‘double y1(double)’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the parts you want.

Simply create your own partial mini_cmath.h header for those functions / globals you need access to (assuming *those* don't conflict!).

As several have noted, there's no way to only #include a given chunk (unless the included header has preprocessor macros to enable such a thing, such as windows.h)

But if you simply declare those functions you wish to use (correctly), and then compile & link (as long as the necessary .lib is included in your link), then you're golden.

---

However, on a more general note - globals are a bad idea in general, but if you absolutely *must* use them for hopefully valid reasons, then you should be putting them in a namespace, and referencing them in your source by fully qualified name:

```
namespace AcmeCorp {
  int g_fubar;
}
AcmeCorp::g_fubar = 9;
```

Comment: so i would simply copy/paste the functions defined in math.h into my own header and link that?

Comment: As long as we're talking about C-runtime style functions, absolutely.  If we're talking STL templates, that's more difficult (if not impossible) to pull off because they tend to be complex, and defined in the headers themselves, and intertwined.  However, even in that case it's possible, if you copy out the portion you need (which doesn't require anything at link if it's fully templated).

Answer (score 4):

Put your code in your own namespace. By using namespace operator (::) you can distinguish variables with the same name (and which are in the same scope).

Comment: does this imply i would have to create my own sqrt function?

Comment: No. You will just use `myNamespace::y1` for your variable. But think again. If I had name clash with standard library, I would always just pick different name for my variable.

Answer (score 3):

Just use them?

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double d = 4.0;
    sqrt(d);
    exp(d);
}
```

You can also explicitly specify the namespace:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double d = 4.0;
    std::sqrt(d);
    std::exp(d);
}
```

You can, if you want, bring in specific names from namespaces without bringing in the whole namespace.  This is done using the `using` keyword.  Please don't create a `#define` for this:

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

int main()
{
    string s = "foo";
}
```

Comment: this does not work - i cannot #include <cmath> because it conflicts with different variables i am using. the point is i want to use a function in <cmath> without including the entire library.

Comment: @Laurbert515 - `#include` makes the preprocessor dump the contents of the included file, there's no selective including.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: <strike>Why should a `y1` conflict with anything in math.h?</strike> Use your own namespace. You'll still be able to use `sqrt` and you can access stuff from your namespace by resolving through `mynamespace::y1`.

Anyway,
`cmath` is an alias of the header file `math.h`.
`std` is a namespace, which contains the `cout` object in `iostream.h`.

So while you can use `std::cout`, you can't do the same scope resolution with a header file. You just have to include `math.h`, or `cmath`.

And you don't need to use a `#define` for cout like that. Just add a `using namespace std` and you won't have to resolve the scope.

And using an entire namespace does not cause any overhead, if that's what you're concerned about. Cheers!

Comment: Depending on platform, you will see things like this in a `math.h` header: `extern double y1 ( double );` - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/y1.html

Comment: y1 is defined in cmath ...


driver.cpp:18: error: ‘float y1’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:524: error: previous declaration of ‘double y1(double)’

Comment: @birryree Ah! Then that's not a part of standard C++, I guess. :P

Answer (score 0):

Just `#include <cmath>`.  If your variable names are such an issue, then rename them.  You can't include just a piece of a file.

Comment: it just seems crazy that something as basic as "y1" conflicts with a predefined function. is there really no way to include ONLY sqrt from a header file?

Comment: I don't see why it seems so strange?  It's just a decleration that was used already, just as if you declared a variable called q1 and tried to define it elsewhere.

Comment: the problem is that y1 is defined as a function elsewhere and i am wanting to use it as a float.

Comment: So then either change your variable name or encapsulate it in a class or namespace if possible.  It doesn't matter what it was defined as by cmath - you can't use it for your own names.

Answer (score 0):

`y1()` is one of a number of POSIX extensions to the C math library. You can remove these extensions by undefining the following macros before including `<cmath>`:

```
#undef _SVID_SOURCE
#undef _BSD_SOURCE
#undef _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

It's also a very good idea in general to avoid putting any of your own names in the global namespace, since there's a good chance of a collision if you use any C libraries. Avoid global variables whenever you can and, if you must use one, put it inside your own namespace.